# dynamically expand a data frame columns using cbind

Tags: r, binding, null, dataframe

I would like to build a data frame in a loop adding a new column each time using `cbind`.  I try the following:

```
test <- NULL
df <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4))
test <- cbind(test, df)
```

This generates an error:

```
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 4
```

What is the correct way to instantiate a blank data frame in R and then bind to it in a loop?

Thanks

Comment: This may get very slow if you have a lot of columns. See the R Inferno for some performance tips http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to create `test` as a structure that has the same number of rows so that `cbind.data.frame` will not throw an error:

```
 test <-data.frame(row.names=1:4)
 df <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4))
 test <- cbind(test, df)

 test
  x
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
```

Two other methods:

```
> test <-data.frame(row.names=1:4)
>      test[['x']] <-c(1,2,3,4)
> test
  x
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4


> test <-data.frame(row.names=1:4)
>      test[1] <-list(x=c(1,2,3,4))
> test
  x
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
```

Comment: What if the columns have unequal lengths? How do you keep them aligned row-wise? Like stuff NAs for missing values?

Comment: In a word ... yes. You pad.

Answer (score 12):

As Roman Luštrik pointed out it may be inefficient to use cbind. You can start with empty list and after loop convert it to data.frame.

```
test <- list()
# inner loop assigment
test <- c(test,list(c(1:4)))
# after loop
test <- as.data.frame(test)
```

Comment: thanks! that's useful for my purposes since i have a large data frame